# What could be the reason for my Schnauzer having a bluish eye?

Tags: dogs, health, vision

I have a miniature Schnauzer, who is 4 years old and in good health, but a couple days ago I noticed that his right eye is bluish and the left eye is normal (dark).

I took two pictures to compare them with each other:

[image: http://imgur.com/IvNN2H0]

[image: http://imgur.com/3ziWe2w]

I set up an appointment with a veterinarian, but in my city I was only able to get an appointment for Saturday, and I'm worried about his situation.

Is this something I worry about? Does it look like a cataracts disease, or maybe an eye injury?

What could cause his eye to be blue, and what can I do before his appointment with the veterinarian this weekend?

Comment: Asking us if a decision made by a DVM makes sense is nonsense in itself. Ask another DVM...

Comment: @Jeremy I don't think it's unreasonable to ask for a second opinion here. We answer behavioural questions even though most of us probably don't have PHDs in animal behaviour. In all the discussions about whether or not medical advice was on-topic or not, it seems to be a common agreement that we shouldn't try to act as veterinarians, but that we could certainly act as supplements to veterinarians.

Comment: @MattS. Behavioral issues are nothing compared to medical issues. Many people have read training books, taken classes, etc... When it comes to behavior, anyone whose read a pamphlet can write an answer. Medical reasons are different. A simple yes or no can change the OP's dog's entire life quality. These questions should not be on topic. But regardless, the question is entirely opinion based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got a veterinarian ophthalmologist at an emergency clinic. And the news is not so good. My baby has an hereditary cataracts, and apparently sees only shadows in the right eye. And the prognostic is attacking the left eye also.

The vet advised a surgery to remove the cataracts as soon as possible, and after put a lens to see properly again. In the next days I will do an evaluation for surgery.

I'm a little afraid. But I believe everything will be alright.

Thanks for the support.